# Tweaking the R readline behavior

Tags: r, interface

The R interactive interface implements the shell-like read line behavior (I have no better words to formulate this...).

For example, pressing Ctrl-W kills the preceding word.

Now, I would like this mechanism to stop at characters other than alphanumeric. For example, if I have entered

```
data.frame(Ant
```

and press Ctrl-W, the whole string `data.frame(Ant` is killed. I would much prefer the Ctrl-W to kill the `Ant` and stop short of the left parenthesis.

Is there a way of tweaking this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of `readline` depends upon the operating system and the IDE.  On Windows, CRTL-W doesn't delete the previous word.  I don't think that there's a trivial way of changing the behaviour.  At a guess, start digging around in:

http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/utils/src/io.c